# IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array in Pro server

Tags: c#

I am getting below error 
IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array while calling the Email id from Active Directory, here is the code and follows the error

```
string propertyName = "mail";
string User = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

string[] Name = Regex.Split(User.Trim(), @"\\");
string username = Name[1];
//string domainname = HttpReq//System.Environment.UserDomainName.ToString().ToLower();
string domainname = Name[0]; //"AsiaPacific";
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=" + domainname + ",DC=cpqcorp,DC=net");
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
search.Filter = "(&(&(objectClass=user)(SamAccountName=" + username + ")))";
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add(propertyName);
SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
string propertyValue = "";
if (result != null)
{
    propertyValue = result.Properties[propertyName][0].ToString();
    //propertyValue = result.Properties.Count.ToString();

}
return propertyValue;
```

Exception Error:

> [IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.]
>   clsCommon.DisplayName()

This is happening when i run the tool in Pro server not coming in if i run local.

Comment: Your `Split` is returning a single element , It appears there is no double back slash in your string, May be you are trying to split on a single backslash, use `"\\"` or `@"\"`,

Comment: `SearchResult` may also be the problem

Comment: Either `Name` only has one element or `Properties[propertyName]` has zero elements.  Use the debugger to find out for sure.

Comment: I am using the "\\" only for splitting,  string[] Name = Regex.Split(User.Trim(), @"\\");

Comment: I have debugged properly it was running and getting the values properly in local but not in published server

Answer (score -1):

solved myself, Changed the Authentication in the Pro server, from Anonymous to Windows authentication. thanks for the replies